# ftplib upload and download get stuck

Tags: python, ftplib

I'm trying to upload a file to my VPS (hosted by GoDaddy) via Python's `ftplib` library:

```
from ftplib import FTP
session = FTP('ftp.wangsibo.xyz','wsb','Wsb.139764')
file = open('source10.png','rb')
session.storbinary('store_source10.png', file)
file.close()
session.quit()
```

However it gets stuck at line 4 (the file is only a few k's and it's taking minutes). The same thing happens when I'm trying to read using `retrbinary`.

I've tried using FileZilla and it worked fine. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FTP.storbinary(command, fp[, blocksize, callback, rest])](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.storbinary)

> Store a file in binary transfer mode. command should be an appropriate
>   STOR command: "**STOR filename**". fp is an open file object which is read
>   until EOF using its read() method in blocks of size blocksize to
>   provide the data to be stored.

`store_source10.png` is not a **command**, you can try to use `STOR source10.png`.

e.g.

```
from ftplib import FTP
session = FTP('ftp.wangsibo.xyz','wsb','Wsb.139764')

file=open('source10.png','rb')
session.storbinary('STOR source10.png',file)

file.close()
session.quit()
```

Comment: Ops, I thought that was just a file name. Thank you!